# htaccess trick to load resources (js/css) below the web root

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to achieve something that I am not sure if htaccess can even do.

What I have is a folder structure:

- myapp

  - some_folder

    - some.js
- www

  - css
  - js

now the web root is pointing at www folder so i can do http://mydomain.com/js/jquery.js and it would work but what I want to do is http://mydomain.com/myapp/some_folder/some.js and it should load some.js and serve it.

Is it possible to do this in htaccess?

Comment: just to clarify, the "myapp" directory is *not* in your webroot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't point to directories outside the current web root from within `.htaccess`.

There is the `Alias` directive but in the .htaccess file, it works only below the web root. It would have to be in the central configuration file to accept absolute paths.

As far as I know, this limitation applies to all other directives that could help here, too (`RewriteRule` etc.)

The only workaround that comes to mind is using symlinks. Whether you can do that, heavily depends on your operating system and access to the server.

Answer (score 0):

you can redirect upwards, just using the .. parent directory identifier.
for example:

```
RewriteRule (.*) ../$1
```

but only if the destination still lies within your webroot.
in your cas it seems not to, so your only chance is to create a symlink/hardlink to that directory or do some file including

alias rewriting in your server cfg file however would work.